# POST (HTTP) + Java : How can I send a specific form-data?

Tags: java

I intend to call a POST API, it requires a form-data as the body to be sent. I need help on how to send form-data.
Following is how I am calling the api:

```
static URL url;
static HttpURLConnection conn;
static String response;
url = new URL("http://" + ApiConfig.URL + endpoint);
System.out.println("URL: " + url);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://blog.morizyun.com/blog/android-httpurlconnection-post-multipart/index.html) that shows how to send form data including files with HttpURLConnection .

Comment: This answer is a bit poor, but the solution that is linked is the only one I found which works for both form data and files without any additional library.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the example of the Oracle website: [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

You can use the following code:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("string=" + stringToReverse); // Write you body here
out.close();
```